# In what situations does make need to target an .h file

Tags: c++, makefile

Under makefiles examples that I have seen, header files are listed (and only listed) as a dependency of a target like this, with there being no specific rule to target the header file in the way that the cc file is targeted in the rule in this example

```
sample1.o : sample1.cc sampleheader1.h
   g++ -Wall -c sample1.cc
```

I have a directory structure like this for my project
    src/hello.cc
    headers/cctz.h

with `cctz.h` being a header file included by `hello.cc`.

However, when I create a makefile for my project, make is complaining that there is `no rule to make target 'cctz.h` needed by `hello.o`. The makefile is in my `src` dir, hence the `../headers` to reach `cctz.h`

```
CPPOPTIONS = -I../headers
all: hello
hello: hello.o
  g++ -Wall -o $@
hello.o: hello.cc cctz.h
  g++ -Wall $(CPPOPTIONS) -c hello.cc
```

So, in my program, I need to `target` the header file, but in other makefiles I have seen (such as I provided a snippet from) the header is only listed as a dependency for the target and there is no rule to make it. What am I doing wrong or why do I need to target the `cctz.h` file in my case (and how do I do it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `make` program looks for files in the makefiles directory first, unless you specify a path to the file:

```
hello.o: hello.cc ../headers/cctz.h
```

`make` doesn't know anything about the compiler options you set in e.g. `CPPOPTIONS`.

You can also set [`VPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html):

```
VPATH = ../headers
```

Comment: why doesn't make know anything about the compile optiosn I set in CPPOPTIONS if I pass that as a variable? (the demo makefile I copied used that CPPOPTIONS variable to set the headers dir)

Comment: @Leahcim Because it doesn't parse variables, and `make` can be used for so many different things (not only to build C++ programs) it can't really understand all options that might possible define search directories.

Comment: ok but I still have to include $(CPPOPTIONS) in the rule g++ -Wall $(CPPOPTIONS) -c hello.cc  for it to compile, so the compiler understands varaibles that make doesn't?

Comment: @Leahcim, make is a building script. It knows very little about what is actually being built and how. It has no idea what CPPOPTIONS is and how to use it. It just uses it as an argument to g++ if you have said so. You might want to consider switching to cmake, which will generate proper makefiles for you.

Comment: @Leahcim The `make` program simply replaces the variable `$(CPPOPTIOS)` with the text it contains when it create the command it runs.